# UK Citizen wanting to move to Mexico

Tags: uk-citizens, mexico

I would like some advice:
I am a UK Citizen/national wanting to move to Mexico.

I would like to get a work or temporary residence visa but I am not eligible for either.(Financials)

I can stay in Mexico for upto 6 months on a tourist visa and I work online (Web Developer) so all my work comes from outside Mexico and I can prove this.

I am worried that if I keep leaving and re entering the country some flags will be raised after time.

**Edit**
Sorry first post on this SO, i'm  not sure what details to share /to not share

Comment: Repeated visa-free entries will flag up at some point, obviously. What exactly do you want advice on if you already know you don’t qualify for a residence visa?

Comment: @Traveller Why do you say it will flag up at some point?

Comment: @Midavalo Because typically countries don’t allow long term frequent visiting / extended stays without the appropriate visa and it therefore seems reasonably safe to assume Mexican Immigration would at least notice the pattern after some indeterminate time. Whether they’d do anything about it is hard to say, but UK to Mexico is quite a trip only to find yourself denied entry and unable to collect personal belongings etc. at the end of it. I guess it depends on the OP’s risk appetite, and the ease with which they can make visa runs to neighbouring countries or elsewhere.

Comment: @Traveller OK.  I guess I wouldn't call it a "flag" if nothing is ever done about it.  Notice, sure, but I don't think it's a flag - particularly if they advise people that this is the way to do it if Residency not granted.

Comment: Great thanks for this information, I am worried about this being an issue but my view is: Im earning from abroad and paying into the Mexican economy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Residente Temporal (temporary residency visa) does not automatically give the right to work in Mexico - you need a work permit endorsement added to the visa.

That said, Mexico allows people to work remotely while living in Mexico, as long as a) you're not taking a Mexican job, and b) all your income is paid into a non-Mexican bank account.  This was the advice given to me by the Mexico Consulate when I was granted my RT.  I was not given a work permit, but was told it was no problem as my work/pay was remote from outside Mexico.

There are many people who live in Mexico on a tourist permit, renewing the permit every 6 months.  Someone I know was advised by the Mexico Consulate that while she didn't meet the financial requirements to obtain residency, she could just continue to renew the tourism permit every 6 months.  She did this for 2.5 years without any problems.  I am also aware of other people who have been doing this without issue for many many years.

Talk with your local Mexico Consulate, they will likely give you the same information I was given.